# Weird index out of bounds exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, uiviewanimation

I am trying to animate the deletion of a view inside a scrollView. the scrollView's subviews are being populated out of an array of objects. each object has a view representing it. sometimes i get an indexOutOfBounds exception when i delete. this is my code of deletion:

```
-(void)deleteView:(UIView *)viewToDelete{
    [self.myObjects removeObjectAtIndex:viewToDelete.tag];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        viewToDelete.alpha = 0.0;
        for (NSInteger index = viewToDelete.tag+1; index<self.myViews.count; index++){
            UIView *view = [self.myViews objectAtIndex:index];
            view.center = CGPointMake(view.center.x,view.center.y-viewToDelete.frame.size.height);
        }
    }]; completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }];

    [self.myViews removeObjectAtIndex:viewToDelete.tag];
    for (NSInteger index=0; index<self.myVies.count; index++){
        UIView *view = [self.myViews objectAtIndex:index];
        view.tag = index;
    }

}
```

Comment: Put [self.myObjects removeObjectAtIndex:viewToDelete.tag]; after [self.myViews removeObjectAtIndex:viewToDelete.tag]; and give it a try..

Comment: That's "out of bounds", not "out of bounce"...

Comment: Index out of bounce exception. Should have thrown it better..

Comment: I know it wasn't strictly.. or even slightly helpful, but when opportunity comes knocking. :)

Comment: @ChrisCooney it was funny. you shouldn't bounce:) yourself to being strict

Comment: I sense a pun war coming on. You DON'T want to throw down with me, son.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is with the animation block

you should know that the animation block is being processed asynchronously, so your last peace of code might get called during the animation process and make a mess in you iteration loop inside the animation block. you should move

```
[self.myViews removeObjectAtIndex:viewToDelete.tag];
for (NSInteger index=0; index<self.myVies.count; index++){
    UIView *view = [self.myViews objectAtIndex:index];
    view.tag = index;
}
```

to the completion block

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs at this point `[self.myObjects removeObjectAtIndex:viewToDelete.tag];`

As soon as you remove one object from array, total number of items will be decreased. So you can not access object at that index.

You should really map these two array self.myObjects and self.myViews.

Comment: it looks like he has to arrays, one holding the objects and one holding the views.

Comment: yes i know he has written this [view removeFromSuperview]; in completion block. probably view is not getting removed and assessed again. while object is moved from array